# one signal : how to display notifications only wehn user is online?

Tags: push-notification, onesignal

I do use onesignal API to send/ receive push notifications.

Is there a way to send/receive web notification only when user is online: if offline, then push is discarded (online = browser opened)

ex: user1 has his browser closed. A notification is sent. 
Normally, he will get it next time he opens his browser. 
Is there a way a discard that notification ?
 (sent when he was offline)

Comment: TBH, i'm trying to understand the use-case? don't we need the push only when user is offline to bring him back to the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this with the TIME TO LIVE option, by default is 3 days but you can set to 0 and the message will be discarded if the user is offline.

[image]

[Source](https://blog.mozilla.org/services/2016/02/20/webpushs-new-requirement-ttl-header/)